# How to use an image from a resource in TWebBrowser?

Tags: html, embedded-resource, delphi-xe8, twebbrowser

I have an HTML file and a JPEG image compiled as resources into my .exe file. The image should be shown in the HTML in a TWebBrowser. I found the following solution in a couple of places on the web:

```
<img src="res://myprogram.exe/rc_myimage" />
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The .rc file is

```
rc_readme RCDATA "readme.htm"
rc_myimage RCDATA "myimage.jpg"
```

(I also found a couple of "solutions" suggesting to extract the image from the resource, and temporarily saving it to the .exe's folder, but I sincerely hope this is NOT the right answer.)

**update**
I also tried to include the .exe's full path, with the backslashes percent-encoded, as per [this webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710218.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<img src="res://D:%5CDelphi%5Cmyprogram.exe/#10/rc_myimage" />
```

but also here the image can't seem to be found. ( The "#10" is the resource type RT_RCDATA, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009.aspx).)

Comment: Show us your .rc file please

Comment: @DavidHefferman I updated the question

Comment: What happens if you use `RT_BITMAP` and a .bmp instead of a .jpg

Comment: Or, perhaps you need to specify the resource type: `res://myprogram.exe/RC_DATA/rc_myimage` or perhaps `res://myprogram.exe/#10/rc_myimage`

Comment: @DavidHefferman BRCC32 chokes on an RT_BITMAP: "bitmap file myimage.jpg is not in 3.00 format". The other suggestion of adding /RC_DATA doesn't work either. But thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: Obviously you don't try to compile a JPEG image with `RT_BITMAP`. Pass in a Windows bitmap, .bmp. My guess is that JPEG is not supported here.

Comment: Yes, I thought already... Still doesn't work. Also tried to add the /RTBITMAP to the path, to no avail.

Comment: Keep trying along these lines

Comment: Load the image into memory, base-64-encode it, and embed it in the page as a "data:" URI?

Comment: Read the documentation: [res protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710218.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Tried including the exe's full path, but it still doesn't work. I updated my question to include this.

Comment: @JorisGroosman: if you read the doc more carefully, omitting the `sType` parameter will default to `RT_FILE` and `RT_HTML` only, neither of which matches your actual resource type. You must include the `sType` parameter to display `RCDATA` or `BITMAP` data. Using the RC you showed, `res://<encoded path to myprogram.exe>/#10/rc_myimage` displays a JPG just fine for me when I try it in a test app, the image appears as expected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I guess I was focusing too much on the path encoding. Unfortunately, when I add the #10 (for RT_RCDATA) like you did, it still doesn't work. Is it possible to upload your test app somewhere? Thanks again.

Comment: @JorisGroosman there is no need to upload the test project. Using an RC of `rc_myimage RCDATA "myimage.jpg"` with `res://<encoded path to myprogram.exe>/#10/rc_myimage` works fine for me.

Comment: Which is what I said right at the start, having read the docs. Oh well!